# Lifetime error for a variable I think I'm not borrowing

Tags: rust

I have a block of code that recursively reads a directory and creates a hash for each file. This is the code:

```
//read the file paths all the way upto individual files
for dir in search_dirs.iter(){
    //read the dir, skip errors (hidden files, syslinks etc) 
    for e in WalkDir::new(dir).into_iter().filter_map(|e| e.ok()) {
        //check if it's a file, continue
        if metadata(e.path().display().to_string()).unwrap().is_file(){

            //"clone" std::path::Path as &str
            let file_path = e.path().to_str().unwrap().clone();
            //create a new FileInfo Object
            let mut file_obj = FileInfo::new(None, None, file_path);
            file_obj.generate_hash();
            file_obj.generate_path_hash();

            //count the num for each file content hash ~ HashMap
            *file_counter.entry( file_obj.get_hash() ).or_insert(0) += 1;

            //HashMap for file path hash and FileInfo Object

            /*If I add this statement I have an Error: E0597
            file_info.entry(file_obj.get_path_hash())
                           .or_insert(file_obj.clone());
            */
        }
    }
}
```

If I add `file_info.entry(file_obj.get_path_hash()).or_insert(file_obj.clone())` I get an error `E0597`.

```
error[E0597]: `e` does not live long enough                                     
  --> src/main.rs:41:33                                                         
   |                                                                            
41 |                 let file_path = e.path().to_str().unwrap().clone();        
   |                                 ^ borrowed value does not live long enough 
...                                                                             
48 |                 file_info.entry(file_obj.get_path_hash() ).or_insert(file_obj.clone());
   |                 --------- borrow used here, in later iteration of loop     
49 |             }                                                              
50 |         }                                                                  
   |         - `e` dropped here while still borrowed
```

**Question**

- I cloned `e`, I don't think I borrowed it.
- I'm not using 'e` anywhere else, so why should the compiler care about it? It can be dropped.

Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: [main.rs](https://pastebin.com/dvC7TiG8) [lib.rs](https://pastebin.com/uHdmFMKX)

Comment: It would have been nice if you had minimized your code further. For testing, I had to create a new Cargo project, add the dependencies and copy-paste two files.

Comment: @kangalioo Oh, I'm sorry. I just started learning Rust. Could you share your version of the code?

Comment: It's ok :) I actually haven't minimized your code though because I've already gotten a good overview

Comment: Please review how to create a [MCVE] and then [edit] your question to include it. We cannot tell what crates, types, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. Try to produce something that reproduces your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) or you can reproduce it in a brand new Cargo project. There are [Rust-specific MCVE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) as well.

Comment: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`FileInfo` contains a reference to a `str`, not an owned `String`. This means that it can only live as long as the `str` that it references.

You tried to avoid that problem by cloning the `e.path().to_str()`. That way, you have a new copy that should not be bound to `e` in any way. That is correct, but because the clone was created in an iteration of the loop, it only lives for that iteration of the loop.

So in the end, cloning doesn't change anything, because the lifetime is still the same (You can try it out).

One solution would be to modify `FileInfo` so that it contains a `String` instead of a `&str`. That way, every `FileInfo` instance can be moved around freely without lifetime conflictions.